# Chrome, how to rearrange bookmarks on the fly up or down a bookmar folder without entering bookmark manager?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, bookmarks, scrolling, bug

I have some folders with a lot of bookmarks in them, I sometimes like to rearrange them, but it won't let me go down or up past the current displayed list, it just freezes at top or bottom as I try to drag.

I know it can be done in bookmark manager but it's kind of a hassle going there everytime, I prefer to do it on the fly, is there a way, for it to scroll up and down the list and not get stuck at the top/bottom?

this is what it looks like, weird.

https://imgur.com/2BBBjsu

Comment: Googled around some more, seems this problem happened to some people, well at least one guy had my exact same problem, but for most it is not an issue, might be something mac specific, not going to redo my whole chrome to fix it though, I guess I can use bookmark manager.

Comment: If you can't see/edit all of your bookmarks in one folder at once, you probably need to start using sub-folders to organize them!  :-)

Comment: yeah, I know, I have a habit of just putting everything into a dump folder and I have thousands of bookmarks in there, should probably organize them all one day.

Answer (score 0):

For me, on my Mac mini with a Dell mouse (don't ask), I can use the middle scroll wheel to move a bookmark past the edges of what is at first visible when I pick up the bookmark.  This is done directly in a bookmark folder on the bookmark bar, and not in the Bookmark Manager.  Dragging the bookmark itself won't cause the visible list to scroll, you need to use a scroll wheel.  I tried the page up/down keys too, they didn't work.

Comment: interesting, I only have a trackpad on a macbook, maybe I can simulate scroll wheel.

Answer (score 0):

This works by emulating the middle mouse, I did so using a preset in bettertouchtool for this function made by the dev

https://community.folivora.ai/t/emulate-a-real-middle-click-including-dragging-with-the-trackpad-e-g-for-cad-programs/1076

you kind of have to use both hands on the trackpad but it works once you figure it out, probably do-able with other programs too.